# Represent multiple parent relationships for entity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Suppose I have these entities (annotations omitted, first property is primary key):

```
data class Person(val personId: Int, val name: String)

data class Occasion(val occasionId: Int, val name: String)

data class Party(val partyId: Int, val name: String, val honoreePersonId: Int?, val associatedOccasionId: Int?)
```

A Party can optionally be thrown in honor of a Person, and can optionally have a specific Occasion it is associated with.

Now I want to get a list of all Parties, but with associated Persons and Occasions if it has any. The documentation describes setting up a one-to-one relationship, but not with multiple parents. In this case it would be a Party with two optional Parents.

Can Room represent this kind of relationship? Can I simply mark multiple `@Relation` annotations on the primary item like this?

```
data class PartyWithAssociatedData(
    @Embedded val person: Person?,
    @Embedded val occasion: Occasion?,
    
    @Relation (parentColumn = "personId", entityColumn = "honoreePersonId")
    @Relation (parentColumn = "occasionId", entityColumn = "associatedOccasionId")
    val party: Party
)

@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM Party")
fun getPartiesWithAssociatedData(): List<PartyWithAssociatedData>
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it will work in that way. Try next data class instead:

```
data class PartyWithAssociatedData(
    @Embedded val party: Party,
    @Relation (parentColumn = "honoreePersonId", entityColumn = "personId")
    val person: Person?,
    @Relation (parentColumn = "associatedOccasionId", entityColumn = "occasionId")
    val occasion: Occasion?
)
```

As for query method it seems it should work without any changes.

Comment: So the `@Transaction` doesn't really care if the table you select from in the query is represented by an `@Embedded` vs. `@Relation` property? It just figures out which property matches the query's table and works out the rest?

Comment: I guess under the hood there would be 3 query. First one is what you put explicitly into the `Query`, 2nd and 3rd - additional queries, that are depend on `Relation` attributes. `Transaction` is needed just for enclosing three queries in single transaction. After getting first query's result Room really matches all gotten columns to fields of `PartyWithAssociatedData`. You can put there all `Party` fields instead of `Embedded` and that should still work. But as for 2nd and 3rd queries' results Room makes instances of objects annotated with `Relation` and sets them as data class fields.